# QDialog focusOut event triggered when clicking on dialog's children

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMainWindow that shows a QDialog when pressing a button.
I want the shown dialog to lose opacity when not in focus, e.g when interacting with the main window, and regain full opacity when it gets in focus.

I've subclassed QDialog reimplementing focusInEvent() and focusOutEvent()

```
void DialogSettings::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
{
  setWindowOpacity(1);
  QDialog::focusInEvent(event);
}

void DialogSettings::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
{
  setWindowOpacity(0.5);
  QDialog::focusOutEvent(event);
}
```

It works as described: low opacity when I interact with main window, full opacity when I click on the dialog.

The problem is that when I click on a dialog child widget (e.g. a checkbox, a push button, ...) the focusOutEvent() is also called, and the dialog is set to half opacity. Also, I'm not able to trigger the focuInEvent() no more (e.g. by clicking on the dialog title bar).

How to prevent the latter behavior, and only manage dialogs/windows focus exchange, ignoring dialog's child focus events?

Comment: From the top of my head 2 options: 1. Use `QEvent::Leave` and `QEvent::Enter` instead of focus events. 2. Set event filter for the children in your dialog. About losing focus completely: try to set/change focus policy of your QDialog's subclass or it's children.

Comment: Leave/Enter are triggered by simple mouse movements, not clicks. Not really what I wanted. I managed to let it work using eventFilter on the dialog (no need to add event filter to the children) (luckily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the desired behavior by setting up an eventFilter instead of using focusOutEvent/focusInEvent.

```
DialogSettings::DialogROI(QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui_(new Ui::DialogSettings)
{
  ui_->setupUi(this);
  installEventFilter(this);
}

bool DialogSettings::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
  if(event->type() == QEvent::WindowActivate)
  {
    setWindowOpacity(1);
    return true;
  }
  if(event->type() == QEvent::WindowDeactivate)
  {
    setWindowOpacity(0.5);
    return true;
  }

  return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```